# Can't talk to Kafka broker on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka

I realize this question comes up a lot.  I've read many threads and blog posts, but here I am.  Long story short, I have a docker container running wurstmeister/zookeeper & wurstmeister/kafka, and then some services running in their own containers.  I'll just mention the NoddJS one for now. Everything works fine at home, using IP addresses (not localhost) so I'm baffled at what the difference is here.  On AWS, it simply "doesn't work" even though it seems to at least connect to the broker in the beginning.  I'm explicitly using internal IPs in the config as I don't want this exposed to anything externally.

Reading around, I've tried 2 setups. 1 works at home (KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME).  1 doesn't (KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS).  Neither work on my EC2 Linux box:

Kafka docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: <internal-ip>
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

NodeJS docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - kafka_my-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1337:3000"
    volumes:
      - "/tmp:/tmp"
      - "/var/log:/var/log"

networks:
  kafka_my-network:
    external: true
```

Then in NodeJS

```
const kafkaHost = '<internal-ip>:9092';
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost});
const producer = new kafka.Producer(client)
const kakfaTopic = 'test';

producer.on('ready', function() {
  console.log(`kafka producer is ready`); // I see this, so I'm assuming all is well
  ready = true;
});

producer.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});

const payload = [
  {
    topic: kafkaTopic,
    messages: JSON.stringify(myMessages);
  }
]

producer.send(payload, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(`Send error ${JSON.stringify(err}`);
  }

  console.log(`Sent data ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
});
```

When I start my NodeJS server, I see that I've connected to a Kafka broker.  I can confirm as well that :9092 is open after checking w/ telnet and/or nc.  Then, when it sends a request, the callback gets an empty error.

I realize KAKFA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is deprecated, so in the name of completion, here is my attempt using ADVERTISED_LISTENERS which failed.  With this configuration I seemed to get the same results at home as I did on EC2.

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://<internal-ip>:9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

EDIT: I will not provide this as a solution, but the bitnami image w/ the following config works.  The main difference is it had a pretty straight forward README that I went through.  I can't be certain if I tried the equivalent config w/ wurstmeister (I tried many - and again, at least one of which in docker containers on my own machine but not on a single EC2 instance).

Note that I did list 'kafka' with an internal IP (not loopback) in /etc/hosts for this.  This should be tantamount to using the internal IP explicitly which I had done above.

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:29092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - my-network

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: My use Docker instead of MSK or Confluent Cloud? Why EC2 instead of on your local machine?

Comment: Also, *internal* IPs are only meant to be used within AWS. And your VPC is probably blocking 9092 by default, anyway...

Comment: As per my post I am only meaning to use this within AWS.  This is all currently on one machine as well so it's not that.  My workaround is to use a different image, which I am tempted to post but I am still curious why the wurstmeister image simply doesn't work for me.

Comment: You've not shown the container logs, so I don't know if it is even started... You can also start one broker using the tools I listed and you don't have to mess with Docker

Comment: The idea is to get them to run in their own docker container for reasons which should be obvious.  Getting it to run out of docker is trivial.

Comment: Inside Docker is not obvious, sorry. That offers almost no performance improvements as you are just starving the JVM of the host memory and CPU

Comment: Not using docker for performance.  In fact I'm putting up w/ a performance hit I'd say.  The idea to containerize is for dependency isolation among other things.  Please check latest edits - this is the config w/ bitnami that "just works".  I tried a bunch of different things w/ wurstmeister - some which worked on my machine but not the ec2 instance (which is exactly the problem containerizing addresses) but to no avail.  I'm still curious what exactly went wrong.  And again, this is all on a single EC2 instance at this point so firewall shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Still not sure why you don't want to use Confluent Cloud, MSK, EKS, or at least CloudFormation/Terraform.... You can do each of these with only one broker as well

Comment: Brand new to Kafka... this seemed like path of least resistance.

Comment: Self hosted Docker on EC2? Absolutely not... https://confluent.cloud/signup